# I am beginner in PHP. I created a Database. How to display the data from database in PHP page?

Tags: php

I have created a `Register.php` page with `name`, `email`, `password`, `gender`, `image` and `login page` with `name`. When `user registers` it's getting successfully inserted to database. When `user logins` it just shows `Welcome Username`.

Now i want to get whole the registered data like name, email, password, gender, image  to be displayed in the `welcome.php` page after `user logins`. How can i do it?

Following is my code.

Register.php

```
<?php

 if(isset($_REQUEST['name']))
 {
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","userdb");

   $target= "images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
   $name= stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']);
   $name= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);
   $email= stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']);
   $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
   $password= stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
   $password= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
   $gender= stripslashes($_REQUEST['gender']);
   $gender= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$gender);
   $image= $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $query= "INSERT INTO regtab(name,email,password,gender,image)VALUES('$name','$email','$password','$gender','$image')";
   $result= mysqli_query($con,$query);

    if($result){
        echo"<div class = 'form'>Registered sucessfully.Click here to <a href = 'login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
 }
 else
   {
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>reg page</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>



<div class="container">
        <div class="row top_margin">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">User Registration</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                           <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name"> Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                            </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                                <input type="radio"  id="gender" name="gender" value="male">Male
                                 <input type="radio"  id="gender" name="gender" value="female">Female

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Image</label>
                                <input type="file" class="" id="image" name="image">
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=”registration_submit”>Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<?php

   }

?>


</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['name']))
{
    session_start();
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "userdb");
    $name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);

     $query = "SELECT * FROM `regtab` WHERE name='$name'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1)
        {
            $name = $_SESSION['name'];


            header("Location: welcome.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div class_class=form>username entered is wrong.Please enter correct name.<br><br>Click here to <a href ='login.php'>LOGIN</a><br> Click here to <a href ='test.php'>REGISTER</a></div>";
        }
}
else
{


?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>reg page</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row top_margin">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">User Login</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                           <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="first_name"> Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                            </div>



                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value=”submit”>Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "userdb")or die(mysqli_error($con));

$query = "SELECT * FROM regtab" ;
$result = mysqli_query($con , $query)or die(mysqli_error($con));
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "Welcome ";
echo $_SESSION['name'];

 ?>
```

Comment: How you can login with Name only? It must be username and password in your login form.

Comment: Also you need to store username/email in session if user inputs the correct username and password. And from username stored in session, you will pick complete information of the user in welcome.php page.

Comment: You can check my answer and replace your code to get the users data in welcome.php page that I have tested at my end. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to modify your code in the below way to get complete `users data` in `welcome.php` page but you need to modify your code to make it more secure. You need to use `MD5` for storing your `password`. And you need to login with `username` and `password` instead of `name`. Most importantly, you need to gain more knowledge to make your code better. In the mean time, update below code that will help you getting data in `welcome.php` page.

login.php :

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['name']))
{
    session_start();
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "userdb");
    $name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);

     $query = "SELECT * FROM `regtab` WHERE name='$name'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1)
        {
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            header("Location: welcome.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div class_class=form>username entered is wrong.Please 
enter correct name.<br><br>Click here to <a href ='login.php'>LOGIN</a><br> 
Click here to <a href ='test.php'>REGISTER</a></div>";
        }
}
else
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>reg page</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href = 
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<div class="container">
<div class="row top_margin">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">User Login</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="first_name"> Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" 
name="name">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
value=”submit”>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.php :

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "userdb")or 
die(mysqli_error($con));

$query = "SELECT * FROM regtab where name = '".$_SESSION['name']."'" ;
$result = mysqli_query($con , $query)or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "Welcome ";
echo $_SESSION['name'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Email:".$row['email'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Password:".$row['password'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Gender:".$row['gender'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Image: <img src='images/".$row['image']."'>";
?>
```

Replace `login.php` and `welcome.php` with the above code, your users data will then start displaying in `welcome.php` page. But you need to follow standard to improve your code. Hope it helps!

Comment: welcome! Don't forget to accept my answer and upvote :)

Comment: can you please tell me how can i add edit and delete  data in these welcome page

Comment: Yes you need to add form in your welcome page as well and then show the data in fields. And when you click on submit button, then your data can be modified.

Comment: You need to make the form like you have made in your register.php page

Comment: And then add the values for all fields like name you have in session : <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>">

Comment: For Email:- <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>">

Comment: And you need to use update query as well after submission of your form

Comment: i have made same form as my register.php page. then i give value="<?php echo $row['name']?>"

Comment: Now make one more page like update.php and give that page in the form action.

Comment: You can check this link for update query, it's very simple: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: If any problem comes then let me know.. Also please don't forget to upvote my answer.

Answer (score -1):

In your login.php put the below code instead of `$name=$_SESSION['name'];`

```
 $_SESSION['name']=$name;
```

Then on your welcome.php, you can access the current user by `$_SESSION['name']`. Now you have the current user and you can retrieve all the data of the current user from the db by using `$query = "SELECT * FROM regtab where name = '".$_SESSION['name']."'" ;`